# how to make item selected/unselected in list of item without reload placeholderview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I would like to make a design like in this picture

[image: picture]

this my code

```
        @Click(R.id.root_width_layout)
        private void onClick() {
            SELECTED_CAR_POSITION = mPosition;

            if(Integer.valueOf(vehiclesBean.getService_type_id())!=4){
                sessionManager.setCarType(SELECTED_CAR_POSITION);
            }

            placeholder.refresh();
             
        }
```

I have to refresh before it selects. but I don't want to refresh
`placeholder.refresh();`

Answer (score 0):

You can save a reference to the last saved item, and when you select select a new item, by reference. you remove the selection state from the old one and set it to the new one, you can add more check if it's null, you just add selection to an item, and if it's the same you do nothing.

In onClick, you should theoretically get View v, as the parameter, i.e. the View that was clicked, from here you can get the reference